# Trying to change an image on Wordpress site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

this is my first question on here so please bear with me if I do something wrong.

I am running a wordpress site using a child theme of the Storefront theme and WooCommerce.  On one of my products I am trying to use a simple piece of javascript which will highlight different areas of a picture when a piece of text is clicked by effectively changing the image to a gif with a flashing red dot.  I learnt that wordpress won't let me do inline Javascript from within the editor and so I have tried a plugin (TC Custom Javascript) firstly and then when that didn't work I tried enqueuing my script.

My code is (I believe) correct as in when tested outside of Wordpress it does what I want it to do.  Also, both the plugin and my enqueued script file work with something else (e.g. when the button is clicked an alert is displayed).  I just can't figure out why the image won't change within WordPress.

My HTML code is as follows:-

```
<img id="theImage" src="https://c-ko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/HP-230_white_1.jpg" width="300" height="300">
<input type="button" value="Click" id="button1">
```

My Javascript code is:-

```
var b1 = document.getElementById("button1");
b1.onclick = pictureChange;

function pictureChange() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById('theImage').src = "https://c-ko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/flashing_dot.gif";
}
```

I have included the actual picture paths to hopefully explain what I'm trying to achieve - I know it may be a crude way of doing things but as I'm sure you can tell from my code I'm not that advanced and this will be fine if only it would work!

I have published the product but hidden it in case anyone needs to see it on the site.  The link is https://c-ko.co.uk/product/dual-channel-infrared-headphones/

(Just to be clear, you need to scroll down until you see the 'adjustable headband' button.)

Thank you in advance for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap everything into an onload listener:

```
window.onload=()=>{
   button=document.getElementById("button1");
   button.onclick=()=>{
       //your gif code
        document.getElementById('theImage').src = "https://c-ko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/flashing_dot.gif";
    };
   };
```

The document object just exists if the window object has completely loaded... Check if the script is embedded into your site using chrome/firefox debugger. Look for errors in the console...

About ()=>{} :
Thats a so called arrow function. it has much shorter syntax than a normal function:

```
var name=(arguments)=>{code};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Jonas, at the moment I've still had no joy but I think something is stopping the script from running - maybe something to do with the theme.  I'm still battling with it....

Comment: Well, debug debug debug

Comment: Update:- I have found that my script is working in some browsers but not others!  It works in Firefox on my Mac but not in Chrome, Safari or Opera.  It works on my Android Browser but not in Chrome.  On my colleagues windows machine it works in IE and his version of Chrome!  I have coded an alert into the script before the image change just to check that the button is working and the alert works on everything - it's literally just the picture change that doesn't work on some browsers.  I'm not getting any errors in the console.  Don't know what to do next?